# Multiple parents hierarchy recursion

Tags: sql, database-design, ssas

```
Master Table
===========
ID NAME
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

Hierarchy table with multiple parents (Note that neither can be primary column due to duplicate values):

```
Relations Table
================
ChildID ParentID  
   3        1
   3        2
   4        3
   4        2
   5        4
```

Hierarchy becomes like (it might not be this linear always):

```
  1         2
  |         |
  3         3
  |         |
  4         4
  |         |
  5         5
```

For reporting purpose I need data in recursive hierarchy format so that I can drill down it. I'm not getting if I can get drill down feature from existing data itself (seems not doable as I can not create recursive parent-child relationship due to duplicate values).

Do you have any ideas? My goal is to finally use this structure as a dimension in SSAS which automatically gives drill down if a table has a self primary key-child key relationship.

Answer (score 5):

Using your example data, I actually get a different tree...

```
Relations Table            Tree
================          =======
ChildID ParentID           1   2
   3        1               \ /|
   3        2                3 |
   4        3                 \|
   4        2                  4
   5        4                  |
                               5
```

Do you actually want two independent trees?  If that's the case, you could introduce an extra field such as a tree id...

```
Relations Table              Tree1     Tree2
=======================      =====     =====
TreeID ParentID ChildID        
   1     NULL      1           1         2
   1      1        3           |         |
   1      3        4           3         3
   1      4        5           |         |
   2     NULL      2           4         4
   2      2        3           |         |
   2      3        4           5         5
   2      4        5
```

Without some extra piece of information, you'll always have problems of branches splitting and merging without a very well formed set of constraints.  For example, if you wanted two linear trees of 1-3-4-5 and 2-3-4-6, your current model would have this...

```
Relations Table            Tree
================          =======
ParentID ChildID           1   2
   1        3               \ /
   2        3                3 
   3        4                |
   4        5                4
   4        6               / \
                           5   6
```

The problem you now have though, is that there are FOUR linear paths...
- 1-3-4-5
- 1-3-4-6
- 2-3-4-5
- 2-3-4-6

What may be required is for you to describe a real world situation, exactly what you want from it, and exactly what you don't want from it.

My typical experience is that, for reporting purposes, any node in a tree should only have one parent, but may have many children.  This means that when climbing up a tree you only have one route, and when climbing down a tree the data separates into sub-nodes.

Having many parents and many children makes a web rather than a tree.  Where you have multiple routes, no matter which direction you traverse the tree.